# R find time when a file was created

Tags: r, file, metadata

I am using R function list.files to get a list of files in a folder. I would also like to record when each file was created, modified and accessed

how can i do that? i tried google search, but didnt find any useful command

Below screenshot is from my Windows machine. I get it when i right click a file name and click "properties"

[image]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Check out [`file.info()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html) for `ctime` and other file properties:

```
## With a single path
p <- R.home()
file.info(p)$ctime
# [1] "2014-11-20 08:15:53 PST"

## With a vector of multiple paths
paths <- dir(R.home(), full.names=TRUE)
tail(file.info(paths)$ctime)
# [1] "2014-11-20 09:00:45 PST" "2014-11-20 09:00:47 PST"
# [3] "2014-11-20 09:00:47 PST" "2014-11-20 09:00:50 PST"
# [5] "2014-11-20 09:00:33 PST" "2014-11-20 09:00:33 PST"
```

Notice the definition of `ctime` isn't necessarily the file's *creation* time:

> What is meant by the three file times depends on the OS and file system. On Windows native file systems `ctime` is the file creation time (something which is not recorded on most Unix-alike file systems).

Comment: This provides me ctime that is the time when the file was created but it don't give me the data about when the original file was created. I can see this by clicking right at the file, choosing "Properties". A window opens and click in the tab "Details". There you can see when the File was Created. But I am interested in the section "Origin": When the content was created?

Comment: I found actually another answer that fits with my question above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539413/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-content-created-time-of-an-excel-file-in-r

Comment: I don't think that ctime ist create time. ctime is change time: change of metadata, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244108/is-ctime-on-linux-always-greater-or-equal-as-mtime).

Comment: @Corina Roca How do you underline text on StackOverflow?

Comment: You can add `extra_cols = F` to make it faster : `file.info(p, extra_cols = F)$ctime`

Answer (score 3):

[`fs::file_info()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/file_info.html) and [`fs::dir_info()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/dir_ls.html) return a data.frame where the rows are files and columns are file characteristics.

```r
p <- R.home()

tail(fs::file_info(p)$modification_time)
#> [1] "2022-05-21 12:54:00 CDT"
tail(fs::file_info(p)$change_time)
#> [1] "2022-05-21 12:54:00 CDT"
tail(fs::file_info(p)$access_time)
#> [1] "2022-07-03 18:50:48 CDT"
```

Like [`base::file.info()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.info.html), notice the definitions of these characteristics are system-dependent and may not be what you expect for your OS.

<sup>Created on 2022-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>