# Rename files to creation date in R

Tags: r, date, rename

I have an R script where I want to download the current copy of the dataset from a remote database, but backup the local version I've been using, with the file's creation date in the title. In a unix terminal I'd use:

```
mv dataset.rds dataset.$(date -r dataset.rds +"%Y%m%d").rds
```

How can I do the same from R? I tried using the following system() function without much luck.

```
creation_date <- system('date -r dataset.rds +"%Y%m%d"')
```

Several variations on that also didn't work. It also doesn't appear that the R date() function has an equivalent to the unix version's -r flag.
Is there another way to get a file's creation date within R?

Comment: Use `file.info` to gather data and create creatione_date, next use `file.rename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file.info` for that. It will give you the time the file was modified, created and accessed the last time.

```
creation_date <- file.info("dataset.rds")$ctime
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out using [R find time when a file was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066620/r-find-time-when-a-file-was-created)

file.info() can give me the creation time using $ctime

```
file.info("dataset.rds")$ctime
```

So then combine it with file.rename(), using paste() to combine the new filename, creation date, and file extension

```
file.rename("dataset.rds",paste("dataset", format(file.info("dataset.rds")$ctime,
 "%Y-%m-%d"), "rds", sep = "."))
```